# Mutual fund wants to get 1% upfront fee (US). Is that within acceptable ranges for a managed bonds fund?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds

Mutual fund wants to get 1% upfront fee (US) plus an annual fixed fee. Is that within acceptable ranges for a managed bonds fund?

Comment: "Acceptable" is pretty subjective.  I'd personally be really hard-pressed to justify paying any front end fees.  If it's a long-term investment and the front-end fee buys you a sufficiently lower expense ratio, though, it might be worth it.  Most funds that have a Class A option (a fund with a front-end fee) have other classes that don't have that fee (though they'd generally have higher fees elsewhere).  https://www.investopedia.com/articles/mutualfund/05/shareclass.asp#targetText=Although%20mutual%20fund%20companies%20can,has%20various%20benefits%20and%20consequences.

Comment: What could you gain from this mutual fund that you couldn't from the myriad of funds with no upfront fee as well as low annual fees?

Answer (score 3):

["Front loaded"](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/front-endload.asp) (and the inverse "back loaded") Mutual funds used to be very common.  They were mostly replaced in the 1980s by [no-load](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/no-loadfund.asp) mutual funds from places like Vanguard.

I've got a managed no-load bond fund through Vanguard, and it's management fee is 0.09%.  According to its web site, the average management fee for similar funds is 0.74%.